# Using RegionIntersection on Regions formed by RegionUnion

Tags: regions

Whenever I try to find the intersection between a two regions, one of which is a derived region using RegionUnion, I get a BooleanRegion with which I can do little.

```
s1 = Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.1];
s2 = RegionUnion[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.1], Sphere[{0.05, 0, 0}, 0.1]];
l = Line[{{-0.2, 0, 0}, {0.01, 0, 0}}];

Show[Region[s2], Region[Line[{{-0.2, 0, 0}, {0.01, 0, 0}}]]]
```

[image]

```
RegionIntersection[s2, l]
```

> BooleanRegion[(#1 || #2) && #3 &, {Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.1], 
>          Sphere[{0.05, 0, 0}, 0.1], Line[{{-0.2, 0, 0}, {0.01, 0, 0}}]}]

```
RegionIntersection[s1, l]
```

> Point[{{-0.1, 0, 0}}]

I am sure this has been answered somewhere else, or that I am missing something basic, but I can not find a reference

Answer (score 4):

I agree that at the present time [`RegionIntersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection) can produce simplifications where the equivalent [`BooleanRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanRegion) version does not. Here is a function that converts a [`BooleanRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanRegion) object into an equivalent [`RegionUnion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionUnion)/[`RegionIntersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection) construct so that these additional simplifications have a chance to fire:

```
simplifyRegion[BooleanRegion[predicate_, regions_]] := With[
    {dnf = BooleanConvert[predicate] /. {Or->RegionUnion, And->RegionIntersection}},

    dnf @@ regions
]
```

Using [`BooleanConvert`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanConvert) produces a boolean predicate in DNF form, which means that [`RegionIntersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection) fires before [`RegionUnion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionUnion). Here is the output of `simplifyRegion` on your example:

```
RegionIntersection[s2,l]
simplifyRegion @ %
```

> BooleanRegion[(#1 || #2) && #3 &, {Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.1], 
>     Sphere[{0.05, 0, 0}, 0.1], Line[{{-0.2, 0, 0}, {0.01, 0, 0}}]}]
>
> BooleanRegion[#1 || #2 &, {Point[{{-0.1, 0, 0}}], Point[{{-0.05, 0, 0}}]}]